# Building nested TreeNode array in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion, primeng

Given a flat one dimensional array of type TreeNode (see interface definition below), I would like to traverse the array and add subsequent array elements as children.

Would be great to do recursively, my shot at non-recursion uses a buffer, but the issue I am facing is how to do `node.children[0].children[0]...children[0]` as notice that there is only one child per parent.

```
    Childify(results: TreeNode[]): any {
    var node: TreeNode;
    var buffer: TreeNode;
    var count: number = 0;

    for (var res of results) {
        if (count == 0) {
            node = res[0];
            buffer = res[0];
            buffer.children = [];
            node.children = [];
        } else if (count == 1) {
            buffer.children = res[0];
        } else {
            node = buffer;
            node.children = [];
            node.children.push(res[0]);
            buffer = <TreeNode>node.children;
        }

        count++;
    }
}
```

Interface definition:

```
export interface TreeNode {
label?: string;
data?: any;
icon?: any;
expandedIcon?: any;
collapsedIcon?: any;
children?: TreeNode[];  <---------------
leaf?: boolean;
expanded?: boolean;
type?: string;
parent?: TreeNode;
partialSelected?: boolean;
styleClass?: string;
draggable?: boolean;
droppable?: boolean;
selectable?: boolean;
```

}

The input:

> TreeNode[] = [treeNode1, treeNode2, treeNode3,
>   treeNode4,...,treeNodeX]

The output is a TreeNode object, nested by the children property (which is also of TreeNode type):

```
TreeNode = treeNode1
treeNode1.children = treeNode2
treeNode2.children = treeNode3
treeNode3.children = treeNode4
treeNodeX-1.children = treeNodeX
```

I don't know how to envoke treeNode1.children[0].children[0]......children[0] dynamically for X number of children in a loop, to assign to the next level of children in treeNode1.

Comment: Based on what are you inserting the nodes? How do you want the resulting three to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know TypeScript but here's how I'd do this in JavaScript:

```js
const input = [ new TreeNode("node1")
              , new TreeNode("node2")
              , new TreeNode("node3")
              , new TreeNode("node4")
              , new TreeNode("node5")
              ];

const output = input.reduceRight((child, parent) => {
    parent.children.push(child);
    return parent;
});

console.log(output);

function TreeNode(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = [];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've built an algorithm for you. I've built it in simple javascript, but it should be easily modifiable to conform to your typescript interface.

And the code is here:

```
var flatNodes = [
    {
        name: 'node1',
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'node2',
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'node3',
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'node4',
        children: []
    },
    {
        name: 'node5',
        children: []
    }
];

function linkNodes(flatNodes) {
    flatNodes = flatNodes.slice(); //copy the list

    flatNodes = flatNodes.reverse();

    for (var i = 1; i < flatNodes.length; i++) {
        var previousNode = flatNodes[i - 1];
        var currentNode = flatNodes[i];

        currentNode.children.push(previousNode);
    }

    return flatNodes[flatNodes.length - 1];
}

console.log(linkNodes(flatNodes));
```

The output is here:

```
{
    "name": "node1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "node2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "node3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "node4",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "node5",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```